# capture key press event using xlib

Tags: key, x11, keypress, capture, xlib

while trying to capture the F1, there is a problem, i can't capture it, because the system hook was execute showing the "help" content before my program,
could anyone help me?
Is there any ways to execute my hook before the system hook.
In Linux, when an Xserver executed an hook, it won't execute the next hook on the same-key press event.
Any helps would be preciate.

Answer (score 1):

There is no “system hook” in X, just programs that started before yours and already grabbed the key (in this case, probably the window manager).   If this is just for your use, change the configuration of the other program.   If this is a program you're making for others, you'll need to make your keys configurable anyway, since you never know what keys the users
have already assigned to other applications to use, and they're more likely to discard your app if you try to force your keybindings on them.